# How to setBounds on a CartoJS 4 boundingBox?

Tags: carto-js

I have tried to find an example on how to **setBounds** on a **carto.filter.BoundingBox** with no success. There is examples of **carto.filter.BoundingBoxLeaflet** which takes **map** as parameter.

```
  const bboxFilter = new carto.filter.BoundingBoxLeaflet(map); //map is a leafLetJS map object
```

The **filter.BoundingBox** documentation says **setBounds** takes a **carto.filter.bounds** object as parameter, but no example anywhere. I tried

```
  var mBnd = map.getBounds();   //map is a leafLetJS map object
  const bboxFilter = new carto.filter.BoundingBox();
  var bnd = carto.filter.Bounds(mBnd._northEast.lat, mBnd._northEast.lng, mBnd._southWest.lat, mBnd._southWest.lng);
  bboxFilter.setBounds(bnd);
```

with no luck.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem this way:

```
var mBnd = map.getBounds();   //map is a leafLetJS map object. this coordinates are for temporal use, they will be replaced with a custom rectangle coordinates
const bboxFilter = new carto.filter.BoundingBox();
bboxFilter.setBounds({ west: mBnd._southWest.lng, south: mBnd._southWest.lat, east: mBnd._northEast.lng, north: mBnd._northEast.lat });
```

Hope it helps someone.